# Install and configure Bacula on Debian 6.0.0

Tags: backup, debian, bacula

I installed Debian version 6.0.0 and I want to configure it as network backup solution using bacula, so I need someone help me to do that. Also, should I add this server to my domain?

Answer (score 1):

Please read through the entire pdf. It has all the information you would need.

http://www.bacula.org/3.0.x-manuals/en/install/install.pdf